# How to wrap a text file or string into a CAN message format in python?

Tags: python, can-bus

I want to send a text file consisting of a string across the CANtact toolkit which accepts only CAN message format (eg [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]or[147,63,24,95,67,22,15,77]) of 8 bytes long. How to convert the text file to such CAN message format preferably in python

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to achieve your possible results. I am not sure if it will work, because I don't know CAN.

If you have a string and want only 8 characters you can do:

```
>>> slice_ = "123456789"[0:8]
'12345678'
```

To convert to bytes:

```
>>> byte_string = str.encode(slice_, "ascii")
b'12345678'
```

From bytes to an array:

```
>>> message = [i for i in byte_string]
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
```

You can now send this message. To convert it back to text:

```
>>> received_text = "".join(chr(i) for i in message)
'12345678'
```

The things that are missing here are reading the file data and process it to the slices (Use a loop). This should be an easy task, but if you have any question on that you are welcome to ask.